# Set Excel Sheet Fields value to Object and save

Tags: java

My task is to read an excel sheet and create the Object and save Into MongoDb.
Using JAVA

my class structure

```
public class emp {

    private int empNo;
    private String empName;
    private double  EmpSalary;  
    private Address address;
            <consider setter  and getter>
}

class Address {

    private  String city;
   <consider setter  and getter>

}
```

and my Excel  sheet structure is

```
EmpId    EmpName    EmpSalary    City
   10    Nitesh     15000        Nanded
```

How to do?

Comment: What's your specific problem ?

Comment: create emp object and call All setter(including Address) set values which will come from Excel Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try JExcelAPI :

- [homepage](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)
- [tutorial](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html)
- [support](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/JExcelApi/)
- [Sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/)

Note that it looks it's not maintained anymore, since the last version (2.6.12) was published on 2009-10-26.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JExcelApi. I load the file, get a byte stream of it (.getBytes()) and then:

```
    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteStream);
    Workbook w;
    try {
        w = Workbook.getWorkbook(byteArrayInputStream);
        // Get the first sheet
        Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
    ...
    //example of getting sheet cell
    sheet.getCell(x,y).getContents();
```

Comment: I am using "org.apache.poi" library